# Is there any proper way to determine section number in table from CGPoint if the section is empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using drag&drop behavior for adding new elements in tableView. When I use

```
    [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(point.x-tableView.frame.origin.x, point.y-tableView.frame.origin.y+tableView.contentOffset.y)].section // point is an CGPoint instance
```

everything works great. But when I hover point under empty section header view, I get previous section number. This approach doesn't work. So I was trying to catch event from `CGRectContainsPoint` in headerView, but I have not succeed, because I can't get section number from current view. I was trying to set tags according to section

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake([tableView viewWithTag:i+1].frame.origin.x + tableView.frame.origin.x, [tableView viewWithTag:i+1].frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height), CGPointMake(point.x, point.y + tableView.contentOffset.y))) {
            [tableView viewWithTag:i+1].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
```

but this approach has wild behavior, not related to real position. I feel myself little retarded and I will appreciate you for any help.

btw: I know, that problem will go away if I add dummy cell in empty section, but I can't do It because of related problems. And sorry for bad english ;)

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you may find UIView's `convertPoint:...` and `convertRect:...` methods useful to clean up your code, instead of manually calculating new points and rects.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I wrote that code quickly and there is a lot of things to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fallowing code, it will give you the indexpath like how your treiving  when you selected tableviewcell.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)cellForReuseIdentiFier:(NSString*)identifier andindex:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
 {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
     cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

     UIButton *circleBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [circleBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(selectSongAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [circleBtn setTag:Selection_Tag];
     [circleBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Demo03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [circleBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(6, 15, 16, 16)];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:circleBtn];

     return cell;
  } 
 -(void)selectSongAction:(id)sender
 {
     CGPoint btnPostion = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:songTable];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [songTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:btnPostion];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution. It's working for me. You have to iterate on each "rectForHeaderInSection:" to see if the location is pointing on one of the section. If one of them contains the CGPoint, get it and move your row to the pointed section.

```
CGPoint location = [longPress locationInView:self.orderTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

int i = 0;
while (i < self.datasource.count) {
    CGRect rect = [self.tableView rectForHeaderInSection:i];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location)) {
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:i];
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```